# Place four elements inside div next to each other, with different widths

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am attempting to put four elements next to each other inside a container div; which all are a different width.

This is my desired outcome:

[image]

Unfortunately, this is what it looks like at the moment:

[image]

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}
p {
  margin: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 11%;
  float: left;
}
button {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Title</p>
  <form>
    <input type="text" class="input">
  </form>
  <button>Apple</button>
  <button>Orange</button>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uLL708jg/

Would `Flex` work for this? If so, could someone show me in an answer?

Comment: Yes...it would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `flexbox` could solve this. This is just a basic setup. On `.container`, put a `display: flex;` and remove all the floats. Then wrap the buttons in a div (`.right` here) and give it `margin-left: auto;` to park it on the right of the screen.

**Edit**

`justify-content: space-between;` will align the three items so that there's space between the items and so the search will be in the middle of the div `.container`. No need anymore of `margin-left: auto;`, though the div wrapper around it is needed. Read more about flexbox and how to use it [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

p {
  margin: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 11%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Title</p>
  <form>
    <input type="text" class="input">
  </form>
  <div class="right">
    <button>Apple</button>
    <button>Orange</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers Roy for your fast response. As shown in my image, how could I put the input field in the middle of the container?